# DRF - Request unique identifier

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is there any unique identifier like `uuid` in `request` object?

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.responses import Response


@api_view(['GET'])
def index_view(request):
    return Response()
```

I need a unique identifier for each request to use it further.

If there is not where to add it? Into `request.META`?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: I need a unique identifier for each request to use it further.

Comment: You can  check out https://pypi.org/project/django-log-request-id/. We are using this to apply unique uuid for each request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not given by default, but you can always create a middleware to add the uuid into each request. `request.META` is a good place to add it since it's a common place to add a property related to a request.

Here is an example code.

```
# ~/apps/core/middleware.py
# Place this file wherever you feel most suitable for your project.

import uuid


class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        request.META["uuid"] = uuid.uuid4()
        return self.get_response(request)
```

Then, on settings, you can add the middleware.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    "apps.core.middleware.SimpleMiddleware"
]
```

You can test using your code above.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.responses import Response


@api_view(['GET'])
def index_view(request):
    print(request.META.get('uuid')) # try to print here to check
    return Response()
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/middleware/

Answer (score 0):

Every request is unique,
say even if `index_view` is called from the same browser multiple times,
every request will be different.

But here are some approaches that might help you.

One way is to use the timestamp of when the request was received

Another could be that you can use query_param and add unique value while calling the request to identify them uniquely in `index_view`